# How to show old Git merged branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, repository

As in the above title I want to show an old merged branch commit history in my Git repository, is it possible? and how?

EDIT: The branch was deleted

Comment: You need to be a _little bit_ more specific. Does the branch still exist? Was it deleted?

Answer (score 2):

Git does not lose history when merging branches. But it does not store branch names with commits either.

So you'd have to find the merge commit and then show the history of its second parent (mergecommit^2). I'm afraid there is no easier way.

Answer (score 2):

If the branch was deleted, you need to start by finding the merge commit. The easiest way to do that (pick one, they both do the same):

```
git log --merges
git log --min-parents=2
```

Then, when you have the commit SHA, you can view the history of its second parent:

```
git log d15d36b^2
```